# The logic behind natural log problems help me figure it out

Tags: calculus

I have an exam tomorrow, and I'm more or less able to understand everything I have, but I don't understand the logic behind derivatives and natural logs. 
[Natural Log Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08pTf.jpg)

This problem here -ln(5x^2+2)
First derivative? No problem. 10x^2 /(5x^2+2)

Second derivative using the division rule of derivatives? I end up getting something that isn't right according to my answer sheet.

I did some digging online I found out I was supposed to remove -10 from the first derivative when looking from the second derivative and then derive from there THEN multiply the second derivative by -10.

Then when looking up the Mean Value Theorem of ln10x [1,e]

Using what I know f'(x) = f(b)-f(a)/(b-a)

I SHOULD end up with 1/x = ln10 But, according to the way my professor solved the problem on example day. It ended up being ln10+lne-ln10/e-1.

How does that even happen? I thought we were finding f(b) - f(a) so where does ln10 + lne come from?

There is something I'm missing logic wise, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: The derivative of $-\ln(5x^2+2)$ is actually $-\frac{10x}{5x^2+2}$.

Comment: I forgot to plug in the minus sign cool. But when i search for the SECOND derivative i end up with something different and strange?

Comment: The second derivative would involve using the quotient rule on the first derivative which, I would imagine, probably does produce something fairly cumbersome.

Comment: I know, but when I USE the quotient rule f'(x) * g - f(x) *g'(x) / g(x)^2 I end up with A result not matching the answer the professor gave me, come on guys I really need help here. I already explained all of this above.

Comment: @Dark_Firaga You **also** have $10x^2$ at the numerator, which is probably the reason why your result is wrong.